# Elasticsearch escape hyphenated field in groovy script

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, escaping

I am attempting to add a field to a document doing something similar to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates. However, I appear to be running into issues due to the field being hyphen separated(appears to be treated as a minus sign) as opposed to underscore separated.

Example body below:
`{"script":"ctx._source.path.to.hyphen-separated-field = \"new data\""}`

I attempted to escape the hyphens with a backslash, but to no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the field using square brackets, i.e. simply do it like this:

```
{"script": "ctx._source.path.to['hyphen-separated-field'] = \"new data\""}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me on 2.x (or maybe other version as well):

```
"script": {
  "inline": "ctx._source.path.to[field] = val",
  "params": {
    "val": "This is the new value", 
    "field": "hyphen-separated-field"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or this will also work

```
{"script": "ctx._source.path.to.'hyphen-separated-field' = 'new data'"}
```